# Multiplication Function

Tags: javascript, function, multiplication

I am trying to multiply some numbers running a javascript function in Visual Studio Code, but I don't think I'm getting results. Here is the function:

```
function multiply(numb1,numb2) {let result = num1*num2; return result;}
```

Here are the arguments I am supposed to test in the above function:

```
multiply(4,7);
multiply(20,20);
multiply(0.5,3);
```

How am I supposed to insert these numbers in the function?

Comment: Your variable names are different

Comment: The examples you gave are exactly how you would call the function with the given arguments. But you need to accept the return of the function and so something with it, like display it. And as pointed out, you have a typo in your function (the variable names).

Comment: `numb1`, `numb2` are your parameters and then `num1` and `num2` is used inside the function. The spelling is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code..in your code there was a typo for the parameters

```js
function multiply(num1, num2) {
  let result = num1 * num2;
  return result;
}

console.log(multiply(4, 7));
console.log(multiply(20, 20));
console.log(multiply(0.5, 3));
```